# material-ui@next throws errors - You can only instantiate one class name generator on the client side

Tags: material-ui, react-router-dom

I am using material-ui@next (1.x) and react-router-dom@4.0.0, on every change in route material-ui is throwing below error

> Warning: Material-UI: You can only instantiate one class name generator on the client side.

I have [uploaded the code snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/6z2jn1xyrw).

So how can I fix this problem and avoid these warnings?

Comment: You should paste the code here instead of providing a link.

Comment: I would have love to share locally but there are 2-3 files, so thought it would be easy to share complete prospective.

Comment: I believe it has been fixed in https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/8367,  have a try of newer version?

Comment: Thanks its working with newer version